# prove $(n!)^{n+1}\mid((n^2)!)!$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove: $(n!)^{n+1}\mid((n^2)!)!$

I tried doing this through coefficient formula. I think there has to be a term which is to be added in proof but i cant figure out what exactly has to be done.

Comment: Have you tried setting up an induction proof?  That would be my first instinct.  When going from $n$ to $n+1$, what is the extra part of each side that wasn't there previously?  Is the new part of the left a divisor of the new part of the right?  Remember if $a\mid b$ and $x\mid y$ then $ax\mid by$

Comment: i did  but i cant get last step true. i might be missing something. i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

HINT: The integers $(kn)!$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$ are all less than or equal to $n^2!$, so

$$\prod_{k=0}^n(kn)!\mid\left(n^2!\right)!\;.$$

The product on the left is a product of $n+1$ factorials.